# How to call a Python function that uses numpy from C++ code

Tags: python, c++, numpy

I have the following Python module (actual module I want to use, has many more functions using `numpy` and `tensorflow`), but this is a representative example to reproduce the issue

```
import numpy as np

def get_random():
    return np.random.random()
```

I want to call the function get_random from the following C++ program:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    Py_Initialize();
    if( !Py_IsInitialized() ){
        printf("Initialize failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    //append path of numpy lib
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('/home/uji300/.pyenv/versions/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include')");
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pRet;

    pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("numpytester");

    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    if ( !pModule ){
        return -1;
    }
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    if ( !pDict ){
        return -1;
    }
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "get_random");
    if ( !pFunc || !PyCallable_Check(pFunc) ){
        return -1;
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < 5; ++i ){
        printf(" ===========> START CALL PYTHON SCRIPT %d <===========\n", i + 1);
        pRet = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);     // call the function
        printf(" ===========> CALLING FINISHED  %d <===========\n", i + 1);

        double result = PyFloat_AsDouble(pRet);            // get the return value by pRet
        printf(" ===========> result = %f <===========\n", result);
    }

    Py_DECREF(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pArgs);
    Py_DECREF(pRet);
    Py_DECREF(pDict);

    // close Python
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The C++ program is then built with CMake and run. The call to the get_random() does not work. It returns -1 every time.

What is the right way to call a python function that uses `numpy` or `tensorflow` functions ?